# Query with multiple annotations slows down

Tags: django, django-orm

I've got a query which returns users with additional info
Here are my simplified models:

```
class Event(..):
    creator = models.ForeignKey('users.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='event_creator_set')


class Participator(..):
    status = models.CharField(..)
    event = models.ForeignKey('events.Event', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='participators_set')
    user = models.ForeignKey('users.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='participations_set')
```

My method from User Manager:

```
 def additional_info(self):
        from events.models import Participator
        participated_events_count = Count(
            'participations_set',
            distinct=True,
            filter=(~Q(participations_set__event__creator=F('id')) & Q(
                participations_set__status=Participator.PARTICIPATED))
        )
        return self.get_queryset()\
            .annotate(created_events_count=Count('events_set',
                                                 distinct=True))\
            .annotate(followers_count=Count(
                'followers_set',
                filter=(Q(followers_set__is_following=True)),
                distinct=True)) \    
            .annotate(
                participated_events_count=participated_events_count)
```

Everything works great without the last annotate, but when I'm trying to add `participated_events_count` value - query performed up to 30 seconds

**UPDATED**
If I remove random annotate with Count - query performs very fast

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.prefetch_related()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) to lookup the related objects and reduce the number of additional queries.

```
return self.get_queryset().prefetch_related('participations_set')/
    ...
```

You can use [Django Debug Toolbar](https://github.com/jazzband/django-debug-toolbar) to get a breakdown of queries on each page.

Comment: I added all needed params to `prefetch_related()`, but it doesn't help. Also I'm building only API, so debug toolbar isn't useful for me

Comment: If you create a simple view with DDT enabled that passes the queryset as context then you will be able to see a breakdown of the repeated queries and exactly what is causing your slowdown. It's hard to tell from your example but I'm guessing the slowdown is because your filter is causing (at least) 3 queries for each object in `participations_set`